# how to parse a portion of an incomplete JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json in this format:

```
[
  "one",
  "Two",
  "Three",
  "Four",
  "Five"
]
```

How can I parse it and put in into a List

I tried NewtonSoft json and it can not read the data. It generates an error.

## Update 1

I used this code:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

and get this error:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a list of strings.  What did you try and what was the error?

Comment: `JArray.Parse`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Please see my update. I already used this command to read the json and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use `JObject.Parse`, but the input is not an object, it's an array.  Use [`JArray.Parse`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm) instead.

```
JArray a1 = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

Or alternatively:

```
List<string> numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

Comment: That worked. How can I convert it to a List<String>?

Comment: @mans: See the updated answer for deserialization into a specific type.  Otherwise I imagine you could loop over the `JArray` and add items to a `List<T>`, or use LINQ to project the `JArray` into a `List<T>`.

Comment: To go from `JArray` to `List<string>` you would use `ToObject<List<string>>()`